# Children’s photos exchanged

Tags: visas, singapore

We received Singapore visas for our family and noticed that both kids had their picture exchanged. Now what to do?

Comment: Very much related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59512/singapore-visa-accidentally-issued-with-old-passport-number-can-i-still-travel

Comment: Who made the error?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions. Closing as unclear until they do.